# SEO Friendly Pagination on Pages With No URL Change

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, seo

My site uses pagination to get to different event pages. The problem is, these conferences on these pages are not getting picked by search engines. Below is my code...

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="first" title="First" onclick="getCoferencesThisWeek(1)"></a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="prev" title="Previous" onclick="getCoferencesThisWeek(2)"></a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="count" onclick="getCoferencesThisWeek(1)">1</a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="count" onclick="getCoferencesThisWeek(2)">2</a>
```

What can I do for SEO so Google will crawl and find all of the conferences on the other pages?

Comment: Main issue is not having any href for crawlers to find. Beyond that there are different ways to accomplish goals. Read the google ajax crawling guidelines

Answer (score 1):

1. Make real pages with real URLs.
2. Link to the real pages instead of to `javascript:;`.
3. Cancel the default behaviour of the link (by returning false if you are going to keep using `onclick` attributes) so that the JS still has the effect you want.
4. Use [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to update the URL and make the back button work.